# Easy way to get to values from JSONArray

Tags: java, json

I recently started working with JSON in Java. We have been setting and getting our values as follows from this JSONArray:

```
[{"productId":"1"},{"productName":"hammer"}]

JSONObject jo = ja.getJSONObject(0);
```

We could easily get the values by calling `jo.getString("productId");` which would return the 1.

The problem is that sometimes we get different types of JSON objects. They look like this:

```
[{"name":"productId", "value":"1"},{"name":"productName", "value":"hammer"}]
```

Is there a way to easily eliminate those predicate name/value and just group the actual name and value together (as in the first example)?

Comment: `{"productId":"1"},{"productName":"hammer"}` is not valid json.  use this link to validate:  https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/

Comment: Please try to explain more clearly exactly what problem you need to solve.  What are the inputs and what is the desired output.  Also, ideally, provide the code you have tried so far and how it is failing.

Comment: Sorry I was doing this off memory, I'll edit post

Comment: Check the JSONObject's from the array if they have "name" as key [boolean JSONObject.has(key) ] to determine if you use it one way or the other.

Comment: I thought about that, but I don't want to have to loop through all the JSONObjects. In some cases the array can have 100+ JSONObjects in it.

Comment: Please explain exactly what you are trying to achieve ? What I understand here is that you want to get attributes without calling them by their name ?

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is no.
The longer answer is that you're not working with JSON, you're working with someone's misunderstanding of JSON.
Both of your examples look a bit like JSON, but they're both bogus.

`[]` is an array.
`{}` is an object.

Your first string `[{"productId":"1"},{"productName":"hammer"}]`
 is an array of two objects, where each object has one property.
It's confusing to put dissimilar objects into an array together, but that's going on in both of your examples.
The second example `[{"name":"productId", "value":"1"},{"name":"productName", "value":"hammer"}]` shows an array of two objects, but again, the objects are dissimilar.
I think what they're going for is more like `[{"productId":"1","productName":"hammer"}]`, so I guess the long answer to your question is that you need to go to whomever is providing this "JSON" and tell them to fix it.

To give you a clearer idea of the correspondence between objects (in Java and otherwise) and JSON, check out the Java program below:

```
public class Product {
    String productName;
    String productId;
    public Product(String productId,String productName){
        this.productName = productName;
        this.productId = productId;
    }
    public String toString(){return toJSONString();}
    public String toJSONString(){
        return "{\"productId\":\""+productId+",\"productName:\""+productName+"\"}";
    }
    public static String arrayToJSONString(Product[] arry){
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append("["+arry[0]);
        for (int n =1;n<arry.length;n++){
            sb.append(","+arry[n]);
        }
        sb.append("]");
        return sb.toString();
    }
    public static void main(String [] args){
        Product p1 = new Product("1","hammer");
        Product[] arry = {p1};
        Product[] arry2 ={p1,new Product("2","shovel"), new Product("3","manure")};
        System.out.println("One object");
        System.out.println("    "+p1);
        System.out.println("An array containing one object");
        System.out.println("    "+Product.arrayToJSONString(arry));
        System.out.println("An array containing three objects");
        System.out.println("    "+Product.arrayToJSONString(arry2));
    }
}
```

Here's the output showing the proper JSON representation:

One object
`{"productId":"1,"productName:"hammer"}`

An array containing one object
`[{"productId":"1,"productName:"hammer"}]`

An array containing three objects
`[{"productId":"1,"productName:"hammer"},{"productId":"2,"productName:"shovel"},{"productId":"3,"productName:"manure"}]`

(Newlines are an artifact of the HTML, not JSON)